How can I copy these vertex transformations to the other sides of the mesh?

I would like to copy the selected shape to the other sides of the mesh. How could I do it without having to do it all over again on each side manually?

Depending on the overall profile, I would recommend you just complete this one side, and then duplicate+rotate it five times.

Are you wanting each flat facing to have the same vertex transformations you show highlighted above? Or are you only wanting the results of the highlighted faces copied across one single axis? If the latter, you can just use a mirror modifier, or alternatively, an Object > Mirror > Global (axis) operation. If the former, the process is more involved, but doable.
